# Extract tag name, attribute and its value

Tags: xml, xslt

The **sample xml file** is shown below

```
<a>
<apple color="red"/>
<banana color="yellow"/>
<sugar taste="sweet"/>
<cat size="small"/>
</a>
```

What should I write in XSLT so that i can get the **sample output** below ?

```
<AAA>apple</AAA>
<BBB>color</BBB>
<CCC>red</CCC>
<AAA>banana</AAA>
<BBB>color</BBB>
<CCC>yellow</CCC>
```

Below is the XSLT file i wrote but I don't know how to extract the value.

```
<xsl:template match="*/*">
<AAA>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</AAA>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
<BBB>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</BBB>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[not(self::sugar or self::cat)]">
  <AAA><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></AAA>
  <BBB><xsl:value-of select="name(@*)"/></BBB>
  <CCC><xsl:value-of select="@*"/></CCC>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <apple color="red"/>
    <banana color="yellow"/>
    <sugar taste="sweet"/>
    <cat size="small"/>
</a>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<AAA>apple</AAA>
<BBB>color</BBB>
<CCC>red</CCC>
<AAA>banana</AAA>
<BBB>color</BBB>
<CCC>yellow</CCC>
```

**Note**: The assumption is made, that each matched element has only a single attribute, which is the case with the provided XML document.

Answer (score 2):

your xml should be as

```
<catalog>
    <fruit>
        <name>apple </name>
        <color>red</color>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <name>banana  </name>
        <color>yellow</color>
    </fruit>
</catalog>
```

XSLT  as:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="catalog/fruit">
      <tr>
        <td><AAA><xsl:value-of select="title"/></AAA></td>
        <td><BBB>color</BBB></td>
        <td><CCC><xsl:value-of select="color"/></CCC></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: my xml file was given like that, not a mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="apple">
    <AAA><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></AAA>
  </xsl:template><!-- and then more of that for banana etc -->

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!-- copy template -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And so on for `banana` etc. If you don't know the *copy (or identity) template idiom* then go googling for it; without it your XSLT life will be miserable.

Comment: the template should be auto match, the code
    <xsl:template match="apple">
should not allow to use
the above sample XSLT code work quite nice but i don't know how to extract the value of it ~